# Java server socket communication is VERY slow

Tags: java, python, sockets

Local on Linux.  It's about 10 seconds for a 20k message.  My guess is my Java is bad and Python is fine.

py client:

```
def scan(self, msg):
    try:
        print 'begin scan'
        HOST = 'localhost'
        PORT = 33000
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((HOST, PORT));
        s.sendall(msg)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
        print 'Received', repr(data)
    except Exception, e:
        print "error: " + str(e)
```

Java server:

```
    ServerSocket service = new ServerSocket(33000); 

    while(true) {

    debug("Begin waiting for connection");

    //this spins
    Socket connection = service.accept();

    debug("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());


    ScanResultsHeader results = new ScanResultsHeader();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
        results = scanner.scan("scannerfake@gmail.com", "123", in);
```

and

public ScanResultsHeader scan (String userEmail, 
                   String imapRetrievalId, 
                   BufferedInputStream mimeEmail) 
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, MimeException, ScannerException {

```
    //how fast would it be to just slurp up stream?
    debug("slurp!");
    String slurp = IOUtils.toString(mimeEmail);
    debug("slurped " + slurp.length() + " characters");
    slurp = slurp.toLowerCase();
    debug("lc'ed it");
    //...
```

My guess is I'm juggling the input streams wrong.  One catch is the "BufferedInputStream mimeEmail" signature is required by the library API scan is using, so I'll need to get to that form eventually.  But I noticed the simple act of slurping up a string takes ludicrously long so I'm already doing something incorrect.

Comment: Maybe putting some performance logging on both client and server can help you determine which of the 2 is really slowing thing down.

Comment: Per my comment to the answer below, I swapped in a C server and confirmed it's lightning fast.  Client is fine, connection is fine, it's failing to efficiently "slurp" in IOUtils using streams I've given it.

Answer (score 0):

Revising my answer....

If you are reading efficiently, and it appears you are, it will only be taking a lot time because either

- You are creating a new connection every time you send a message which can be very expensive.
- You are not sending the data as fast as you think.
- The message is very large (unlikely but it could be)

There are plenty of examples on how to do this and a good library you can use is IOUtils which makes it simpler.

You should be able to send about 200K/s messages over a single socket in Java.

---

If you have a sends X bytes protocol using Big Endian you can do this.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( ...
int len = dis.readInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
dis.readFully(bytes);
String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: the code example uses IOUtils already; in fact, the call to an IOUtils method appears to be what's taking the longest amount of time.

Comment: I confirmed if I put a C server on the port instead of Java server it's lightning fast, including the "slurp" step (which of course in C just means write to a char[] buffer).  Problem is definitely Java and probably in my code, or theoretically but not likely in the IOUtils call.

Comment: hmmm interesting. I know java can handle 10k less than 10sec for sure. I have done few hundred k messages less than 10 seconds. Probably you want to do time logging around the steps you think is taking long time?

Comment: On a fast PC I have done 350K small messages per second in a single thread. This is used a persisted connection. Using asynchronous messaging I have got this over a million messages per second. The typical round trip latency was around 10 micro-seconds.  To get faster that this I used shared memory via a memory mapped file. This supports 5-20 million messages per second with round trip latencies of 100 - 300 ns depending on size and complexity (e.g. 128 bytes being slower than 16 longs). My point is; Java is not slow, but I can't see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think my issue is the connection is still open while my slurp is attempting to finish.  Server is waiting for an end of input, and it doesn't get it until the client gets sick of waiting and closes the connection.  So it's a cute situation in which "doing it totally wrong" manifests as "it works, just slowly."  Going to reprogram the client/server to use an "I'm sending X bytes" protocol.
If anyone knows of a Java subclass of BufferedInputStream that does this would be appreciated, for now writing my own subclass that pretends input ends after X bytes.

Comment: Need to use a subclass of BufferedInputStream since my API wants that, ergo DataInputStream won't work.

I wrote my own subclass that only reads up to X bytes after which point it does the same thing as an end-of-input would do.  This cured all my problems.  This is definitely low level enough that I would expect it to be in a popular library, but, I'm lacking Google search terms.

Comment: How does BufferedInputStream know how many bytes to read if you are not using DataInputStream?

Answer (score 0):

Original problem was that the client isn't sending an end-of-input so the "slurp" operation keeps waiting for more stuff to cross the connection.

Solution was to implement an application-layer protocol to send the size of the message in advance, then stop listening for more message after that many bytes.  I would have preferred a  standard library -- something like, FiniteInputStream extends BufferedInputStream and takes a size as an argument, but wrote my own.

Comment: Takes a size as an argument to what? `BufferedInputStream` has a size argument in the constructor, and `DataInputStream.readFully()` takes an implicit or explicit size argument.